# Trying to use line comand in gem: gem install shopify_theme

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I am new to ruby and am trying to use the line command:

```
gem install shopify_theme
```

However, I get an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'shopify_theme' for main:Object
from <rb>:2
from C:/Ruby21/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'
```

I assume this has something to do with my local files? I've used Dir.chdir to target my folder. Also, I have the gem file here as well.

ref: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme

Thank you and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The command should be run from the command line (`cmd.exe`), not from within Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in the ruby console. Exit the ruby console and use cmd.exe!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help!

I switched to command prompt where now I get this message: 
`C:\Windows\system32>gem install shopify_theme
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'shopify_theme' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Windows\system32>
`

Comment: Looks like you don't have a valid SSL certificate. Go on https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme and scroll down to the "common problems" section and you might find the solution to your problem.

Comment: More accurately, that error message means that api.rubygems.org doesn't have a valid SSL certificate.